# Auto running a script in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a script that auto spams pictures of nicholas cage on the desktop
I have this script right now but what I want to do is make it automatically run as soon as the USB is plugged in

```
 import shutil
 src = ('Kim.jpg')
 dst = ('H:/profile/desktop/Nic')
 count = 1
 while count < 10:
     shutil.copyfile(src, dst + str(count) + ".jpg")
     count += 1
```

Comment: Remind me never to give you access to my computer ;)

Comment: Just using it as a senior joke for school :D

Comment: Is the code going to be running off a USB drive? Do you have to support Windows and other platforms? Does it only have to work on specific machines you control? While you can certainly write `autoconf.inf` files to make it work for Windows, the user typically has to approve autoexecution these days on any Windows version since Windows 7. You can also compile your python code into an executable using something like `py2exe` or `cx_freeze` and load it with your [`autorun.inf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf)

Comment: Only windows computers Yes it will run off of a usb drive

Answer (score 2):

**Assumption**: You are using Windows.

Almost on every new windows platform you need to approve an autorun of any executable so no leads here. But here is an alternative using some social/psychological engineering:

Convert your program to a standalone executable using a tool like `py2exe`. I assume that after conversion your file is named `spammer.exe`. Then paste this file in the USB and super-hide it by opening Command Prompt inside your USB and typing:

```
attrib +h +s +r spammer.exe
```

Now create a shortcut with and icon of a typical folder of Windows and name it something attractive (if you know what I mean) and point it to `spammer.exe`. The user (in excitement) clicks at it and Kaboom!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're on a version of windows that isn't too old and you have physical access to the machine in question, you should be able to follow these instructions:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7

Create a .bat file that executes your script. You could even have the script sleep for a random (or semi-random) period of time before going off.